# GZip an entire directory

Tags: linux, gzip

i used the following:

```
gzip -9 -c -r <some_directory> > directory.gz
```

how do i decompress this directory ?

I have tried

```
gunzip directory.gz
```

i am just left with a single file and not a directory structure.

Comment: Wow, I've just tried it. It seems you have all your files, concatenated and then compressed, in your `directory.gz`. How many files are there, were they important?

Comment: if you execute `gzip -l directory.gz`, you can see list of all files and directories inside zip file

Comment: is there a way to get them back?  theyre somewhat important.

Comment: this will help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93158/109344

Comment: For future reference, you want to use tar, zip, 7z or some other container format to bundle multiple files together.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already mentioned, gzip is a *file* compression tool and not an archival tool. It cannot work with directories. When you run it with `-r`, it will find all files in a directory hierarchy and compress them, i.e. replacing `path/to/file` with `path/to/file.gz`. When you pass `-c` the gzip output is written to stdout instead of creating files. You have effectively created one big file which contains several gzip-compressed files.

Now, you could look for the gzip file header/magic number, which is `1f8b` and then reconstruct your files manually.

The sensible thing to do now is *to create backups* (if you haven't already). Backups always help (especially with problems such as yours). Create a backup of your `directory.gz` file **now**. Then read on.

Fortunately, there's an easier way than manually reconstructing all files: using [binwalk](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk), a forensics utility which can be used to extract files from within other files. I tried it with a test file, which was created the same way as yours. Running `binwalk -e file.gz` will create a folder with all extracted files. It even manages to reconstruct the original file names. The hierarchy of the directories is probably lost. But at least you have your file contents and their names back. Good luck!

**Remember: backups are essential.**

(For completeness' sake: What you probably intended to run: `tar czf directory.tar.gz directory` and then `tar xf directory.tar.gz`)

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  It seems that running `gunzip directory.gz` will just result in a concatenation of the original files, without any additional metadata.  I previously wrongly concluded from this fact that `directory.gz` must just consist of the files concatenated and then compressed, but you are correct, and in fact it contains the files individually gzipped and then concatenated after gzip, so it contains the gzip header for each file. Unfortunately the OP suggests they have already done `gunzip directory.gz` before asking the question, so have probably destroyed these headers already.

Answer (score 2):

gzip will compress 1+ files, though not meant to function like an archive utility. The posted cmd-line would yield N compressed file images concatenated to stdout, redirected to the named output file; unfortunately stuff like filenames and any dirs would not be recorded.  A pair like this should work:

(create)

```
tar -czvf dir.tar.gz <some-dir>
```

(extract)

```
tar -xzvf dir.tar.gz
```